# Xamarin Forms Labs - Texting

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am using the xamarin forms labs package at the moment and I was wondering how I can use the phone feature from xamarin forms labs and send a text to the specified number

Comment: Its better not to use XLabs as they discontinued their contribution to xamarin.

Answer (score 6):

In `IPhoneService` there is:

```
 void SendSMS(string to, string body);
```

iOS impl:

```
public void SendSMS(string to, string body)
        {
            UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl(new MonoTouch.Foundation.NSUrl("sms:" + to));
        }
```

Android impl:

```
 public void SendSMS(string to, string body)
        {
            SmsManager.Default.SendTextMessage(to, null, body, null, null);
        }
```

WP impl:

```
public void SendSMS(string to, string body)
        {
            new SmsComposeTask{ To = to, Body = body }.Show();
        }
```

To call it:

```
var device = Resolver.Resolve<IDevice> ();
device.PhoneService.SendSMS("5015551212", "a test sms message");
```

Comment: How do i call it in the class though?

Comment: It seems to still be there in the current source: https://github.com/XForms/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/blob/d679815e4340fce3f5675e4a1e27b8683f024699/src/Xamarin.Forms.Labs/Xamarin.Forms.Labs/Services/IPhoneService.cs#L49

Comment: how come it says it doesnt exist thhen? have you tried it

Comment: Yes, a few versions ago.  Are you running it on a device with phone service?

Comment: yes, i am running it on iphone, i just called var device = Resolver.Resolve<IDevice> ();
device.PhoneService.SendSMS("5015551212", "a test sms message");

but keeps saying phoneservice doesnt have a definition for SendSMS

Comment: Is it getting registered?  https://github.com/XForms/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/blob/master/samples/Xamarin.Forms.Labs.Sample.iOS/AppDelegate.cs#L80

Comment: Yes:

 var resolverContainer = new SimpleContainer ();
   resolverContainer.Register<IDevice> (t => AppleDevice.CurrentDevice)
    .Register<IDisplay> (t => t.Resolve<IDevice> ().Display)
    .Register<IDependencyContainer> (t => resolverContainer);
   Resolver.SetResolver (resolverContainer.GetResolver ());

Comment: I'll try it when I get home.

Answer (score 2):

The iOS SMS sending was not tested and it previously wasn't working correctly as the URI method doesn't allow message body. If you get the latest source it has now been updated and tested (finished the implementation last night). You can run the sample project and test sending your current GPS location with E-mail and SMS.

https://github.com/XForms/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/blob/master/samples/Xamarin.Forms.Labs.Sample/ViewModel/GeolocatorViewModel.cs

This is the SMS code for iOS:

https://github.com/XForms/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/blob/master/src/Xamarin.Forms.Labs/Xamarin.Forms.Labs.iOS/Services/PhoneService.cs

```
    public void SendSMS(string to, string body)
    {
        if (this.CanSendSMS)
        {
            var smsController = new MFMessageComposeViewController()
            {
                Body = body,
                Recipients = new[] { to }
            };

            UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController.PresentViewController(smsController, true, null);
        }
    }
```